# JMSCorrelationID in SOAP over JMS

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws

I implemented a simple example of SOAP over JMS using the wls12.1.2 with JAX-WS where my web service producer and consumer are both setup in two different web logic servers. 
I have used the Future `response.isDone()` to poll for the response.

1) As we are implicitly using JMS, I was wondering whether there is anyway to retrieve the JMSMessageId or JMSCorrelationID from the `BindingProvider.getRequestContext()` or **response object** ? [ at Webservice Client End i.e, consumer ]

2) Is there a way to get the JMSMessageId at the Webservice Provider end? Is there anyway to set the JMSCorrelationID at the Provider end to JMSMessageId if the JMSCorrelationID in the incoming message is null ?

As I can see, the JMS headers are not exposed at the request or response level in the WebService client or server. So does it make sense to look or set these variables JMSMessageId or JMSCorrelationID?

Please guide,